# vb.net backgroundworker CancelAsync not work

Tags: vb.net

**I have a stop problem in the backgroundworker**, I use the following commands for backgroundworker:

---

update codes

```
Private Sub UnpackSystem_DoWork(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles UnpackSystem.DoWork
    Dim worker As System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker = DirectCast(sender, System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker)
    For i As Integer = 1 To 100
        If worker.CancellationPending Then
            e.Cancel = True
            Exit For
        End If
        worker.ReportProgress(i, i & " iterations complete")
        Threading.Thread.Sleep(250)
        Dim oProcess As New Process()
        Dim oStartInfo As New ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe", "/c bin\Imgtool\simg2img.exe tmp/system.img tmp/system.img.ext4")
        oStartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden
        oStartInfo.CreateNoWindow = True
        oStartInfo.UseShellExecute = False
        oStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = True
        oProcess.StartInfo = oStartInfo
        oProcess.Start()
        Dim sOutput As String
        Using oStreamReader As System.IO.StreamReader = oProcess.StandardOutput
            sOutput = oStreamReader.ReadToEnd()
        End Using
        TextBox8.Invoke(Sub() TextBox8.AppendText(Environment.NewLine & sOutput))

    Next i

End Sub

Private Sub UnpackSystem_ProgressChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.ProgressChangedEventArgs) Handles UnpackSystem.ProgressChanged
    Me.ProgressBar5.Value = e.ProgressPercentage
End Sub

Private Sub UnpackSystem_RunWorkerCompleted(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs) Handles UnpackSystem.RunWorkerCompleted
    If e.Cancelled = True Then
        TextBox8.AppendText(Environment.NewLine & "Canceled!")
    ElseIf e.Error IsNot Nothing Then
        TextBox8.AppendText(Environment.NewLine & "Error: " & e.Error.Message)
    Else
        TextBox8.AppendText(Environment.NewLine & "Done!")
    End If
End Sub
```

and, I use the following code to stop backgroundworker proccess ...

```
Private Sub Button55_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Button55.Click
    If Me.UnpackSystem.IsBusy Then
        Me.UnpackSystem.CancelAsync()
    End If
    Dim cmd() As Process
    cmd = Process.GetProcessesByName("cmd")
    If cmd.Count > 0 Then
        Process.GetProcessesByName("cmd")(0).Kill()
    End If
End Sub
```

But it not be canceled, Where is my problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are only testing whether a cancellation is pending when the `DoWork` event handler first starts, which of course it will not be at that stage.  In order for the background task to be cancelled later on, you would have to actually test whether a cancellation is pending later on.

There's no magic here though. As I said, in order to cancel, you have to actually test whether a cancellation is pending within the `DoWork` event handler.  That test can only come between other lines of code. Once you call that `ReadToEnd` method, you are going to read the stream to the end, whether the user has requested cancellation or not. You obviously can't test for a pending cancelation until that call returns

Comment: Thank you
Can you give an example? Unfortunately, did not notice well

Comment: You don't need another example because you already have one: your own code. You already know how to test whether a cancellation is pending. All I've said is that you need to do that in other places in your code if you want to be able to cancel the work at those places. Consider this. Let's say that there's a noticeboard at your workplace. You get to work and the first thing you do is check that noticeboard and it's empty. If you never check the noticeboard again all day, will you ever see a notice that someone put up at lunch time? No you won't, so you have check again later. This is the same.

Comment: [Here are some examples](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?471889-Using-the-BackgroundWorker-Component) of using a `BackgroundWorker` that I created some years ago. [Post #19](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?471889-Using-the-BackgroundWorker-Component&p=3291206&viewfull=1#post3291206) shows how to handle cancelation.

Comment: thanks I updated my first post
please look. It does not work again with these changes